# Problem when converting a date time to string with Php and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, string, date

I have a problem getting a data type date from SQL Server to Php at the moment of executing it, below message appears.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string in

```
$sql1="select id,name,date";
$output1= array(
        array( 'none' )
    );
executeSQL($sql1, $output1);

   ?>
<table>
<thead>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>date</th>
</thead>
   <tbody id="fbody">
    <?php
    foreach($output1 as $key1){
?>
    <td><?=$key1[0];?></td>
    <td><?=$key1[1];?></td>
    <td><?=$key1[2];?></td>
<?php           
    }
    ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is generated by key1[2] if I remove that data if it works.

Comment: You must be using some kind of framework that is converting DATE or DATETIME column data to a DateTime Object. What framework?

Comment: What does a `var_dump` of $output1 show you?

Comment: You could try `$key1[2]->format('dd/mm/yyyy');`

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateTime::format()

```
$key1[2]->format('dd/mm/YYYY');
```

Documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php